# Why are columns that are not variables appearing in my R dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am encountering an issue with an R dataframe.

The dataframe contains columns that are not recognized as variables.
These new columns contain the other columns' names including the symbol '$'.

I cannot delete these columns from the dataframe.

Would anyone have an idea about what these columns are, why they are not considered as variables, and why I cannot delete them?

Here is a fraction of what appears when I use str() on the dataframe:

(...)

```
$ EDU_MAX_1: Ord.factor w/ 8 levels "NAP"<"NONE"<"ED1"<..: NA NA NA   
$ EDU_MAX_2 : chr  NA NA NA NA ...  
$ age_14 :'data.frame': 6 obs. of  61 variables:   
..$ leeftijd : num  14 14 14 14 14 14   
..$ geboortejaar num  1985 1985 1985 1985 1985 ...
```

(...)

The problem seems to be linked to the variable age_14 which then seems coupled to each column.

When I export the dataframe to an excel file, these columns do not appear in the exported file.

Many thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: It sounds like you may have a nested column or columns.  But, as @user438383 has already said, it's impossible to say exactly what the problem is without a minimal reproducible example.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: thank you for your answers, I added more information to the question

Comment: As suspected, your column `age_14` is a data.frame rather than (as usual) a simple vector. How did you generate the data.frame?

Comment: I created it by using a mutate() function to compute a new variable (namely age_14), which obviously failed. I did not know a data.frame could contain another data.frame. do you have any idea how I may erase it ?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it simply by erasing the variable age_14 from the data.frame. Many thanks!

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg